# Regex.Replace replaces more than bargained for

Tags: c#, .net, regex, iis

I'm writing some test cases for IIS Rewrite rules, but my tests are not matching the same way as IIS is, leading to some false negatives.

Can anyone tell me why the following two lines leads to the same result?

```
Regex.Replace("v1/bids/aedd3675-a0f2-4494-a2c0-32418cf2476a", ".*v[1-9]/bids/.*", "http://localhost:9900/$0")
Regex.Replace("v1/bids/aedd3675-a0f2-4494-a2c0-32418cf2476a", "v[1-9]/bids/", "http://localhost:9900/$0")
```

Both return:

```
http://localhost:9900/v1/bids/aedd3675-a0f2-4494-a2c0-32418cf2476a
```

But I would expect the last regex to return:

```
http://localhost:9900/v1/bids/
```

As the GUID is not matched.

On IIS, the pattern tester yields the result below. Is `{R:0}` not equivalent to `$0`?

**What I am asking is:**

Given the test input of `v[1-9]/bids/`, how can I match IIS' way of doing Regex replaces so that I get the result `http://localhost:9900/v1/bids/`, which appears to be what IIS will rewrite to.

[image: IIS Regex Matching]

Comment: Your input strings start with `v1/bids/` that is why the output is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point here is that the pattern you have matches the test strings at the start.

The first `.*v[1-9]/bids/.*` regex matches 0+ any characters but a newline (as many as possible) up to the last `v` followed with a digit (other than `0`) and followed with `/bids/`, and then 0+ characters other than a newline. Since the string is matched at the beginning the whole string is matched and placed into Group 0. In the replacement, you just pre-pend `http://localhost:9900/` to that value.

The second regex replacement returns the same result because the regex matches `v1/bids/`, stores it in Group 0, and replaces it with `http://localhost:9900/` + `v1/bids/`. What remains is just appended to the replacement result as it does not match.

You need to match that "tail" in order to remove it.

To only get the `http://localhost:9900/v1/bids/`, use a capturing group around the `v[0-9]/bids/` and use the `$1` backreference in the replacement part:

```
(v[1-9]/bids/).*
```

Replace with `http://localhost:9900/$1`. Result: `http://localhost:9900/v1/bids/`

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(v%5B1-9%5D%2Fbids%2F).*&i=v1%2Fbids%2Faedd3675-a0f2-4494-a2c0-32418cf2476a%0D%0Av1%2Fbids%2Faedd3675-a0f2-4494-a2c0-32418cf2476a&r=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9900%2F%241)

**Update**

The IIS keeps the base URL and then adds the parts you *match* with the regex. So, in your case, you have `http://localhost:9900/` as the base URL and then you match `v1/bids/` with the regex. So, to simulate this behavior, just use `Regex.Match`:

```
var rx = Regex.Match("v1/bids/aedd3675-a0f2-4494-a2c0-32418cf2476a", "v[1-9]/bids/");
var res = rx.Success ? string.Format("http://localhost:9900/{0}", rx.Value) : string.Empty;
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/FqI0Al)

Comment: I've added some more information to my question. The issue is not how to correctly write the regex, but how to test that whoever wrote it didn't miss the .* part in the end. So that my tests will match that of IIS.

Comment: `{R:0}` is `$&` (or `$&`). The `v[1-9]/bids/` matches the input string partially that is why there is a match. `$0` will hold the whole text matched with the regex pattern. What is expected?

Comment: I want to retrieve the string that the IIS rewrite module will actually rewrite to. In this case, it will be `http://localhost:9900/v1/bids/`, which is incorrect. Meaning that someone wrote an incorrect regex for the rewrite rule. The correct regex could be `v[1-9]/bids/.*`. Given the `v[1-9]/bids/`regex as input, I need to verify that IIS will indeed rewrite to the full path including the Guid. Which it does not.

Comment: Test, not correct. I have a unit test that verifies that, given the string `v1/bids/aedd3675-a0f2-4494-a2c0-32418cf2476a`, it will test the supplied regex and return `http://localhost:9900/v1/bids/aedd3675-a0f2-4494-a2c0-32418cf2476a`rather than the URL without the Guid.

Comment: I think I see now. But do you really think IIS uses a `Regex.Replace`? Isn't that more like a `Regex.Match()`? The whole matched text is appended to the base URL.

Comment: Very good point. I've replaced the Regex.Replace with Regex.Match, then manually replace $0 with match.Value. I'll accept your answer. It's up to you whether you want to update the answer. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the confusing question :D